# Android Jack compiler: how to enable incremental mode?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been using Jack&Jill compiler to take advantage of some of the JAVA 8's features. But since then my compile time is quite slow (around 1 minute instead of a few seconds).
I've seen [here](https://source.android.com/source/jack.html) that by default the incremental mode is not activated.

> Enabling incremental builds
>
> Currently incremental compilation is not enabled by default. To enable
>   incremental builds, add the following line to the Android.mk file of
>   the project that you want to build incrementally:
>
> `LOCAL_JACK_ENABLED := incremental`

But i can't seem to find the Android.mk file :-(.

Could you help me with that ?

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm mistaken you're trying to enable incremental builds for an app rather than for compiling the Android Open Source Project (AOSP). Android.mk is a make file for the AOSP.

To enable incremental builds for your app you want to set `jack.incremental` to true in additional parameters in your module level build.gradle -

```
android {
...
    defaultConfig {
    ...
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
            additionalParameters("jack.incremental" : true)
        }
    }
...
}
```

See here for more information - https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/jackandjill